# Is it possible to add index to database table through R(RMySQL)

Tags: database, r, indexing, rmysql

I have created a table output and connected to database through RMySQL, and now I need to add index to the table, I searched around but didn't found what I need in R language, please help.

A small example of the table would look like this:

```
mth <- c(rep(1:2,5))  
day <- c(rep(10,5),rep(11,5))  
hr <- c(3,4,5,6,7,3,4,5,6,7)  
v <- c(3,4,5,4,3,3,4,5,4,3)  
A <- data.frame(cbind(mth,day,hr,v))
```

The index I need should include: "mth" + "day" + "hr".
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `dbSendQuery` to send SQL statements to the server. So you can [create your table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html) and/or [add indices](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html) using SQL, and afterwards write your data using `dbWriteTable` with `append=TRUE`.